# List has multiple data types in a string format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm given a list of grades

```
# Grades.py
grades=["D 100","D 50", "D 92","D 87","M 83","D 0","D 73","M 86"]
```

The goal of the assignment is to calculate the average of the grades which should be around 87% I believe, but first I need to replace the lowest grade with a 100 so 'D 0' should now equal 'D 100'. Next you are required to remove the lowest grade from the list. D 73 should be deleted. The new list should look like this

```
# Grades.py
grades=["D 100","D 92","D 87","M 83","D 100","D 73","M 86"]
```

Next I need to average the grades. (D)daily= 40% and M(Major) = 60%

So after somehow finding the lowest grade changing it to a 100 and removing the lowest grade completely I need a way to convert the list to integers, *but when i convert to integers I have no way of keeping track of what is daily and what is major.* So my one of my main questions is *how can I convert the list of strings into integers and still know what is major and what is daily?* Also i tried thinking of a way to convert the list into a dictionary, but since there are multiple D's and M's, there is no way to create a dictionary... 
I'm stomped. So if you could please provide a detailed answer on your thought process and what i need to work on It would be greatly appreciated, and i will mark your answer.

Here is my code so far..

```
# Grades.py
grades=["D 100","D 50", "D 92","D 87","M 83","D 0","D 73","M 86"]

intg = [int(i[2:]) for i in grades] #makes a list of ints 
print intg # [100, 50, 92, 87, 83, 0, 73, 86]
```

The final output should be 87%

Thanks in advance

- Allen (avbirm)

Comment: Please don't down vote this without an explanation of why. I tried being as detailed as possible. I spent a lot of time writing this question so please tell me if i need to update or change something. I have pretty valid question if you continue reading.

Comment: *Okay, so my computer science teacher asked the class to work on these stupid programming problems that seem to be inefficiently made.* - is efficiency a problem here? Because this is very basic. Why not do it one step at a time?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I deleted that line, why is this basic? I'm still a beginner/intermediate programmer. I don't understand how i could make all those calculations automatically while they are in string format. I could convert them to ints but i need to keep track of the daily and major grades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
code = [ grade.split()[0] for grade in grades ]
num = num = [ 100 if not int( grade.split()[1]) else int( grade.split()[1]) for grade in grades ] # replace 0 to 100

indexs  = [ i for i,item in enumerate(num) if item == min(num) ] # find min 
#remove min in code and num
num = [ item for i, item in enumerate(num) if i not in indexs]
code = [ item for i, item in enumerate(code) if i not in indexs]

#weight grade based on code then average
numD= [ n for c,n in zip(code,num) if c == 'D' ] 
numM= [ n for c,n in zip(code,num) if c == 'M' ]
final  =  sum(numD)*0.4/len(numD) +sum(numM)*0.6/len(numM)
```

## output

86.86

Comment: This is the complete solution so i check marked thank you.

Comment: @avbirm thank you.pleas let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 1):

Step-by step solution:

```
In [1]: grades=["D 100","D 50", "D 92","D 87","M 83","D 0","D 73","M 86"]

In [2]: weights = {'D': 0.4, 'M': 0.6}

In [3]: temp = sorted([(g[0], int(g[2:])) for g in grades], key=lambda (_, g): g)

In [4]: temp
Out[4]: 
[('D', 0),
 ('D', 50),
 ('D', 73),
 ('M', 83),
 ('M', 86),
 ('D', 87),
 ('D', 92),
 ('D', 100)]

In [5]: grades = temp[2:] + [(temp[0][0], 100)]

In [6]: sum(weights[w]*x for w, x in grades) / sum(weights[w] for w, x in grades)
Out[6]: 88.18750000000003
```

Comment: I cannot manually delete the items in the list. I need the program to do that for me

Answer (score 0):

```
grades=["D 100","D 50", "D 92","D 87","M 83","D 0","D 73","M 86"]
summD=0
summDi=0
summM=0
summMi=0
for i in grades:
    if i[0]=='D':
        summD+=int(i[2:])
        summDi+=1
    elif i[0]=='M':
        summM+=int(i[2:])
        summMi+=1
summ=((summD/summDi)*0.4)+((summM/summMi)*0.6)
print summ
```

Comment: This doesn't calculate a weighted average. This is just the average of all values unweighted.

Comment: This is how i ended up solving it. Although i stole your summ=((summD/summDi)*0.4)+((summM/summMi)*0.6) line. Now i just need to figure out a way to delete lowest grade. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sum up all values for each type (daily or major), divide by the number of values in that type, then apply the weighting.

```
from __future__ import division # If using Python 2.x

WEIGHTS = {'D': 0.4, 'M': 0.6}

grades=["D 100","D 50", "D 92","D 87","M 83","D 0","D 73","M 86"]
grades.sort(key=lambda gr: int(gr[2:])) # Sort by value
grades[-1] = grades[-1][:2] + str(100) # Set the last to 100
grades = grades[:-2] + grades[-1] # Drop the second to last

accumulator = {}
counter = {}

for grade in grades:
    accumulator[grade[0]] = accumulator.get(grade[0], 0) + int(grade[2:]) # Sum the grades by type
    # The get method allows a default value to be used
    counter[grade[0]] = counter.get(grade[0], 0) + 1 # Count the grades of each type

final_grade = 0
for type in WEIGHTS.keys():
    average = accumulator[type] / counter[type] # Calculate the average for each class
    final_grade += WEIGHTS[type] * average # Apply weighting
```